# ObjectDataSource/Grid - Dynamic columns

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid, objectdatasource

I have a requirement for an ASP.NET screen that will show a list of products, and to the right will be columns for each 'Wholesaler' in the system, with their price for each item as the item in each column.

I will be using the Telerik RadGrid in this, and the users must be able to filter/page - so I'm assuming I need to use an explicit data source. I have begun creating an ObjectDataSource, with the following structure:

```
    public string ProductRange { get; set; }
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public decimal TradePrice { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Wholesaler, decimal?> WholesalerPrices;
```

And I am creating my columns dynamically like so:

```
            WDBDataContext dc = new WDBDataContext();
        List<Wholesaler> wholesalerList = dc.Wholesalers.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
        gvProductRange.Columns.Add(new GridBoundColumn() { UniqueName = "ProductRange", HeaderText = "Product Range", DataField = "ProductRange" });
        gvProductRange.Columns.Add(new GridBoundColumn() { UniqueName = "Product", HeaderText = "Product", DataField = "Product" });
        gvProductRange.Columns.Add(new GridBoundColumn() { UniqueName = "TradePrice", HeaderText = "Trade Price", DataField = "TradePrice", DataFormatString = "{0:c}" });
        foreach (Wholesaler wholesaler in wholesalerList)
        {
            gvProductRange.Columns.Add(new GridBoundColumn() { UniqueName = wholesaler.ID.ToString(), HeaderText = wholesaler.Name, DataField = wholesaler.ID.ToString(), DataFormatString = "{0:c}" });
        }
```

However, how am I going to be able to transform the data returned from the objectdatasource at runtime to bind to these correct columns - if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is "gvProductRange" grid view? Why do not you just assign gvProductRange.DataSource = wholesalerList?

Comment: It is - I can do that, however this list is just the wholesalers - no associated columns for the products. And also by using .DataSource, I can't use paging/sorting/filtering